# Python Find columns of second dataframe with matching index to first datframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes.

**Input data**

```
# First df mainly consists data provided by the user 

fdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_data'],data=[10,14,1],index=['alpha','beta','gamma'])

        user_data
alpha   10
beta    14
gamma   1

# Second df is basically a default data consisting kind of analysis I can run based on the data in the first dataframe provided the user
sdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AD_analysis','BGD_analysis','ABG_analysis'],
             data=[[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,0]],index=['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'])
sdf = 
         AD_analysis    BGD_analysis    ABG_analysis
alpha          1           0                 1
beta           0           1                 1
gamma          0           1                 1
delta          1           1                 0
# Above table basically tells us that we can do AD_analysis if alpha, delta values are given by the user in the first df
```

So, I want to know kind of analysis (sdf) I can run based on the data provided by the user (fdf).

**Expected answer:**

```
# Since delta is not given and I cannot run any analysis associated with this parameters
# Possible analysis with given data is 
['ABG_analysis']
```

**My approach:**

```
# find common index
com_idx = fdf.index.intersection(sdf.index)

if len(com_idx)==3 & com_idx.isin('alpha'):
    print('ABG_analysis')
if len(com_idx)==3 & com_idx.isin('delta'):
    print('BGD_analysis')
if len(com_idx)==2 :
    print('AD_analysis')
```

Too many if statements does not convince as a best pythonic approach. Can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Do you have to use all the data provided by the user?

Comment: @mozway yes! that is mandatory. I should use all the data provided user and run all the possible analyses with it. In above `sdf`, as you know, there are three analysis but I cannot run `delta` parameter associated analysis since it is missing from user. So, I should drop all analysis that compulsory need this parameters, in this case, `AD_analysis`, `BGD_analysis`

Comment: I meant the other way around. What if you have an analysis that only requires alpha and beta?

Comment: I reverted to my edit. You cannot use sets in a DataFrame constructor and you had the wrong order of the columns.

Comment: @mozway, now I realized the mistake. I used dictionary`{ }` to name the columns instead of list `[ ]`

Comment: this was actually a [**`set`**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) (`{1,2,3}`), and sets are unordered (`{1,2,3} == {3,1,2}`) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to identify the analyses for which no required data is missing. You can use:

```
# get indices not provided by user
diff = sdf.index.difference(fdf.index)

# ensure they are not required for an analysis
sdf.columns[~sdf.reindex(diff).any()]
```

Output: `Index(['ABG_analysis'], dtype='object')`

If you want to ensure that all data is used (an analysis requiring only alpha and beta would be excluded):

```
sdf.columns[sdf.reindex(fdf.index).all() 
           &~sdf.loc[sdf.index.difference(fdf.index)].any()]
```

Used inputs:

```
fdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['user_data'],data=[10,14,1],index=['alpha','beta','gamma'])

sdf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['AD_analysis','BGD_analysis','ABG_analysis'],
             data=[[1,0,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1],[1,1,0]],index=['alpha','beta','gamma','delta'])
```

Comment: If you see in the user data (fdf), `delta` is actually a missing parameter. So, `AD_analysis` is not expected answer

Comment: @Mainland your DataFrame constructor has an issue, you used sets in place of lists. Let me update your question. For me this gives AD having all 1 except for delta.

Comment: With the correction of your DataFrame constructor, this gives `ABG_analysis`

Comment: Can you please update the question with corrected dataframe constructor. I don't see it yet. Thanks a lot for correcting the question.

Comment: @Mainland It is updated. Please make sure to refresh the page (you previously overwrote it)

Answer (score 1):

Get the indices provided by the use from your second table. Then subset the columns where all the arguments are equal to 1.

```
sdf.loc[fdf.index].eq(1).all(0).loc[lambda x:x].index

Index(['ABG_analysis'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I appreciate your online answer. But My expected answer is `ABG_analysis` since `delta` is a missing parameter from the user (first df) and `AD_analysis` needs `delta` (Second df)

Comment: @Mainland the problem is not the code but the data you provided. Check it again, the first column is `ABG_analysis` while the last column is `AD_analysis`. I am sure you need the last column and not the first column

Comment: I am confused. Please, have a look at the printed `sdf` in the above question and I even reprinted the sdf created df line. I see same. I don't know why the ['AD_analysis'] is logical answer instead of `[ABG_analysis]`

Comment: @Mainland copy the data you provided and run that data. Print it on your screen and you will see that it is different from the printed data. Unless you change your data. Note that in the data `ABG_analysis` is the 1st column and NOT 3rd, in the printed format, `ABG_analysis` is the 3rd column. Thats why you are confused. The code provided is correct

Comment: I updated your (previously valid!).output to match the corrected question ;)

Comment: My apologies! you had a correct answer. I did not use a proper data frame constructor. Thanks to @mozway